# Adding line breaks to c# comments for Intellisense

Tags: .net, intellisense, code-documentation

Does anyone know how to insert a line break into a summary comment in order for the line break to be reflected in Intellisense documentation?

To clarify, assume code documentation..

```
/// <summary>
/// Some text documentation
///  - a line break - 
/// Some more documentation
/// </summary>
public void SomeMethod() { }
```

So when using this method Intellisense offers a summary for the method formatted like this:

> Some text documentation
>
> Some more documentation

**(Note - the 'para' tag doesn't create empty line breaks - I've tried it!)**

Comment: A "para" is half answer (it's actually double break), beginning and end of line gets truncated. To enforce break a line at the beginning and the end of summary add following "<para>&#129;</para>" (&#129; character get omitted - actually non visible and zero space).

Comment: As of Visual Studio 2019, you can add line breaks using `<br/>` in xml documentation. Refer the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734549/12001603).

Answer (score 77):

Try using this.

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Paragraph 1.</para>
/// <para>Paragraph 2.</para>
/// </summary>
```

But I don't think you can have an actual empty line.
Empty para tag gets ignored.

Comment: I thought you just wanted a line break. I don't think you can have an actual empty line.

Comment: how does MS do it with exceptions in methods for example?

Comment: Exceptions are separate tags in the XML.  It's not a blank line in the summary, it's just rendering different sections of the documentation

Comment: A slightly nicer version:

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Paragraph 1.</para>
    /// <para>Paragraph 2.</para>
    /// </summary>

Comment: Sorry for the ugly formatting, but stupid stackoverflow does not allow to change a comment after 5 minutes and prevents any decent formatting anyway. Proper sample see in next comment.

Comment: Basically replace "`<para>XYZ</para>`" by "`XYZ<para/>`"

Answer (score 47):

Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para> [Non-Breaking Space] </para>
/// </summary>
```

`[Non-Breaking Space]` is obtained using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd> (using the Numpad).

It will show up as an empty new line.  I know this is old, but it worked for me today.

Comment: +1: I **finally** have a place to write //Magic, do not touch.

Comment: Just something I want to say: WOW!

Comment: That maybe the most awesome and yet horrible thing to happen simultaneously at so many of the same levels that I have ever seen.  For adding empty lines, I'll use Al Erickson's suggestion of `&#160;` but for doing indenting, this is way nicer.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, we have a winner!

Comment: Oldsk00L! That brings me back.

Comment: Get in my son! Fantastic

Comment: Alt + 0173 looks more like magic. It's the invisible character and works, too.

Comment: How is there no accepted answer on this question?  This should 100% be the accepted answer!  Looking back, I guess the question was just asked badly.  I'm sure the question was meant to ask how to insert a carriage return.

Comment: how to use Alt+255 in VS 2015? when i try Alt+255 in VS 2015 nothing happens

Answer (score 28):

```
/// <summary><br />
/// <para>To treat comment line like a DIV tag, surround them with PARA tags.</para><br />
/// <para>To add a break with whitespace, add the following line:</para><br />
/// <para>&#160;</para><br />
/// </summary>
```

Comment: `<br />` alone worked for me.  Using the `<para>` tags created too much padding which pushed the rest of my comments beyond the overflow.

Comment: `<para>&#160;</para>` was the thing I was looking for, tnx :)

Comment: `<br />` doesn't work in VS 2017.

Comment: `<br/>` DOES work in VS 2019.

Comment: should be accepted answer still works in vs 2022 despite its pretty old html tag

Comment: As a shorthand, you can also use an empty tag at the end of each line: `<para />`.

Answer (score 7):

Your only hope is probably something cludgy like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>line one</para>
/// <para>_</para>
/// <para>line two</para>
/// </summary>
```

Comment: cludgy yes, but thats as close as ive got so far

Answer (score -3):

Well, it is Xml.  Maybe `&#10;&#13;`

Comment: nope that doesn't do it either ...