# Multiline XML Comments in VB.NET and Visual Studio Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, xml-comments

I'm trying to put newlines in my XML Comments in VB.Net. I've read two other posts about C#,

[XML multiline comments in C# - what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547327/xml-multiline-comments-in-c-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

[Adding line breaks to comments for Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467202/adding-line-breaks-to-comments-for-intellisense)

But the suggested `<para>` or `<br/>` tags don't work. This,

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' <para>Line one</para><br />
    ''' <para>Line two</para><br />
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property Speed As Double
```

Still appears like this:

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: This is a documented limitation. No change in VS2010.  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/301904/xml-documentation-para-tag-does-not-work-in-vb-net

Comment: @HansPassant just a thought ... your comment is more useful (and has 10 upvotes) than the single answer here. Should be the accepted answer here (I nearly didnt see the comment). Except that the link is broken ... which is a separate issue.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As time goes by, bugs get fixed. This works now in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

[image: screenshot]

<sub>(It might work in earlier versions as well, but I don't have them installed anymore.)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Now its better to use VS 2012 which will do the same as it does in C#

[image]

Comment: No. You are using C# but the asker uses VB.NET.

Comment: It does not work for VB.Net in VS2012. Pl specify for VB.Net