# how to write description for method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML multiline comments in C# - what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547327/xml-multiline-comments-in-c-sharp-what-am-i-doing-wrong)
>   [Multiline XML Comments in VB.Net and Visual Studio Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070737/multiline-xml-comments-in-vb-net-and-visual-studio-intellisense)

I want to have some description for my method

```
/// <summary> 
/// Perform a divide by b
///      e.g a = 1, b = 2
/// will return 0, since (1/2) = 0.5
/// </summary>
/// <returns>int value</returns>
public static int Div(int a, int b)
{


    return (a / b);
}
```

and i want the description show in the same format that i type..
however, those text will always display in oneline.

is there any tag that i can use to ask visual studio to include all those space and new  line?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML multiline comments in C# - what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547327/xml-multiline-comments-in-c-sharp-what-am-i-doing-wrong), [Adding line breaks to comments for Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467202/adding-line-breaks-to-comments-for-intellisense), [Multiline XML Comments in VB.Net and Visual Studio Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070737/multiline-xml-comments-in-vb-net-and-visual-studio-intellisense)

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the code you've included or is it merely an example? There is a tag for providing sample implementations of your code that you could use if the code you've provided is the extent of what you're after.

Comment: You do, of course, realize that a method accepting two integer parameters and performing integer division and returning an integer is not going to return 0.5, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe putting your lines in `<para />` tags works.

```
///<summary>
///<para>line1</para>
///<para>line2</para>
///</summary>
```