# how to get inline linebreaks like \n for intelicense not paragraphs

Tags: c#, comments

I know i can use < para /> to create multiline function comments

```
 /// <summary>
 /// updates the car scrolling.<para />
 /// there are also colors 
 /// <para />while clearall will remove all  </summary>
 /// <param name="status">optional to add a new car  </param>
 public void UpdateDrawing(int updatestatus = bgcar.color.none)
```

but that behaviour isnt like a linebreak \n it rather behaves like a double line brake  ( \n\n ). Is there a way to have only a single line break.
So textblocks could be created for intellisence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML multiline comments in C# - what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547327/xml-multiline-comments-in-c-sharp-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: What about `environment.newline` ? and did you mean intellisense? It looks like @mjwills is correct with that link

Comment: Read my question.
Not a duplicate i've tried <br/> and <br />as well but its ignored by intellisense. While that <para /> causes empty lines and doesnt behave like inline \n  also environment.newline isn't available in /// commments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>updates the car scrolling.</para>
/// <para>there are also colors</para>
/// <para>while clearall will remove all</para>
/// </summary>
```

[image: Intellisense]

Comment: Did this help @user3800527 ?