# How to place the code example in the XML comment?

Tags: c#, xml-comments

I have a XML comment like that.

```
/// <summary>
/// Lorem ipsum
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entity"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

I'd like to place inside it a piece of the (multiline) code. How can I do that ?

### Edit

Here's the info about multiline code [Adding line breaks to comments for Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467202/adding-line-breaks-to-comments-for-intellisense)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`<code>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8hahtxf) and [`<c>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te6h7cxs) XML tags

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// <c>Place your code here</c>
/// </summary>
/// <code>
/// More code here
/// </code>
```

Per comment, in the `<summary>` you can use a [`<c>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te6h7cxs) tag and outside `<summary>` you can use a [`<code>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8hahtxf) tag.

Comment: no. If inside the summary, [`<c>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8hahtxf) should be used. [`<code>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8hahtxf) is for code that appears *outside* the summary. Take a look at [the example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w4cf933).

Comment: `<c>` is just inline code, `<code>` is bigger code blocks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304821/15488899) is actually a more correct hint as when `code` is used as an example [it should be placed inside an `example` tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#code). Also, note it should be _inside_ of `<summary>` or `<remarks>` to make Visual Studio actually show it in IntelliSense.

Answer (score 7):

To add an example, use the

```xml
<example> 
<code>
Put your example here.
</code>
</example>
```

tags.

Comment: My formatting was off. I'm not sure how to get < example> to show in the answer without adding a space in the tag.

Comment: Also, note it should be _inside_ of `<summary>` or `<remarks>` to make Visual Studio actually show it in IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

See MSDN:

- [XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)
- [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)

One should note, though, that the XML documentation comments are just that—XML—and the compiler will process **any** valid XML tag: it's semantics are dependent on your [documentation processor](http://www.doxygen.nl).

Annex E of [ECMA 334: C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) aka [ISO 23270: Information technology — Programming languages — C#](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042926_ISO_IEC_23270_2006%28E%29.zip) specifies a standard set of XML documentation markup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but here's my best shot:

I typically place code examples inside an `<example> </example>` tag.

```
/// <summary>
/// Lorem ipsum
/// </summary>
/// <example>
///    Put you're example here.
/// </example>
/// <param name="entity"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```