# VB.NET How to add new line in the documentation of the class

Tags: .net, vb.net, comments

I would like to add documentation for a class in VB.Net. I would like to add some examples and some xml tags in class documentation. The problem is in Object Browser the text is not formatted and not possible to pass to new line. All comments are in the same row.
I tried all different tags from this post "[Adding line breaks to comments for Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467202/adding-line-breaks-to-comments-for-intellisense) " and from Microsoft page "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc".
But, it work for C# and it doesn't for VB.NET.
For testing I created a new c# project.

Is it still possible to format the class documentation or add just the line break in VB project?

Comment: XML documentation [isn't C# specific.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-xml-tags-for-documentation-comments). It's not meant to generate well formatted text for Object browser though. It's meant to generate XML files that will be converted to docs by tools and displayed by  Intellisense or Objet Browser. You didn't post what you tried so it's hard to know whats wrong. Check the `.xml` files generated from the docs. How do they differ? Were they generated in the first place or did you forget the switch to generate them?

Comment: Yes, the XML documentation generated is identical in VB.NET and C#. But the view in VS Object Browser is different.

Comment: The VB project documentation is displayed completely flat, but the same class from the assembly is displayed formatted. The C# project class in VS Object Browser is displayed correctly formatted.
Other issue, the not all XML tags works: `<para>` - works, `<list>` - doesn't.
I use VS Ultimate 2012, projects uses .net framework 2.0